# Why does functools.partial not detected as a types.FunctionType?

Tags: python, functools

In my code I need to detect if a variable is a function or not and preform some actions on it.

Everything went well until I now created a partial function using `functools` and suddenly some of my tests fail:

```
import types
import functools

def f(s):
    print(s)

l = lambda s: print(s)

pf = functools.partial(f, 'Hello World')
pl = functools.partial(l, 'Hello World')
test_f = isinstance(f, types.FunctionType) # True
test_l = isinstance(l, types.FunctionType) # True
test_pf = isinstance(pf, types.FunctionType) # False
test_pl = isinstance(pl, types.FunctionType) # False
```

Why is there a difference between those? Both varieties are callable... Even more importantly, how can I detect if some variable is a function or not even when it's a partial function if I can't use `types.FunctionType`?

Comment: Why do you need to check if something is a function explicitly?  Is it good enough to check if that something is [`callable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#callable)?

Comment: *`types.FunctionType`, `types.LambdaType` - The type of user-defined functions and functions created by `lambda` expressions.* — clearly doesn't include whatever `partial` returns.

Comment: @mgilson it's possible, I'm not entirely against it if there is no other solution, but was hoping there is

Comment: @deceze the docs claim that a function is returned: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html

Comment: @OferSadan The docs say: "Return a new partial object which when called will behave like func"

Comment: Oh wow, stupid of me not to notice :)

Comment: @OferSadan Happens to the best of us

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) is a *class* with a `__call__` method, it says in the documents:

> Return a new `partial` **object** which when called will **behave like** *func*

(bold emphasis added by me)

We can confirm this in our Python REPL:

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> add_one = partial(sum, 1)
>>> type(add_one)
<class 'functools.partial'>
```

A Python equivalent would be something like this:

```
class Partial:

    def __init__(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
        self.func = func
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.func(*self.args, *args, **self.kwargs, **kwargs)
```

So it creates a simple wrapper object around the function, and an object like this simply isn't a function. `types.FunctionType` only works on actual functions.

What you're looking for is a way to check if an object is *callable*, for that you can use the built-in [`callable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#callable) function:

```
>>> callable(sum)
True
>>> callable(3)
False
>>> callable(functools.partial(sum, 1))
True
```

Comment: Nice answer, but are you sure it's an object like that? The docs claim it's a function: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html

Comment: @OferSadan -- No, the docs claim that it's _roughly equivalent_ to the function listed.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, you don't *need* to know if something is a function.  Frequently, all you care about is that the object is *callable*.  To check this, python has a builtin function called [`callable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#callable).

Note that just because `callable` returns `True`, it does not mean that calling the object will succeed.  However, the same could easily be said for calling functions :-).

---

If you really only want to handle functions and `partial` objects, then you can write your check as:

```
isinstance(obj, (types.FunctionType, functools.partial))
```

But this isn't sufficiently "ducky" for my tastes.

Comment: `isinstance(obj, (types.FunctionType, functools.partial))` please no, this is just begging for future bugs